# Sticky area in single row and column in css grid

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I am facing the problem with possibility to make only one area sticky in the CSS grid.

How it looks in the code:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    gap: 32;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 478px;
    grid-template-areas:
        'Images Details'
        'Tabs Tabs';
}
.child1 {
    grid-area: Images;
}
.child2 {
    align-self: flex-start;
    grid-area: Details;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
.child3 {
    grid-area: Tabs;
}
```

So the section `Images` is much bigger (bigger height) than `Details` and what I want to achieve is to make `Details` sticky when scrolling down, but once I reach the bottom of `Images` it should stop moving down. For now area `Images` overlaps `Tabs` because it is sticky for the wrapper.

Any idea how to fix it?

Demo
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-a8znlr?file=styles.css

Answer (score 1):

The solution you request is not achievable with pure css and html, however you can do this with some javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const images = document.querySelector('.child1');
  const details = document.querySelector('.child2');

  const handleScroll = () => {
    const imagesRect = images.getBoundingClientRect();
    const detailsHeight = details.offsetHeight;

    if (imagesRect.bottom - detailsHeight < 0) {
      details.style.position = 'absolute';
      details.style.top = `${images.offsetHeight - detailsHeight}px`;
    } else {
      details.style.position = 'sticky';
      details.style.top = '0';
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will fix your problem.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  gap: 32px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 478px;
  grid-template-areas:
    'Images Details'
    'Tabs Tabs';
}

.child1 {
  grid-area: Images;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child1 img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.child2 {
  grid-area: Details;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.child3 {
  grid-area: Tabs;
}

.child2 img {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).